# different bytes are decoded to the same string in Python 3.7.4 on CenOS 7.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos7

The following python code

```
b'\xe4\xb8\xaa'.decode('utf-8')
b'\xc2\xb8\xc3\xb6'.decode('utf-8')
```

display the same string `'个'` but not equal in Python 3.7.4 on CentOS 7.3. However, in Python 3.7.5 on macOS 10.15, the first and second line display the string `'个'` and `'¸ö'`, respectively, which meets the UTF-8 standard.  I don't know why there is a weird error in Python 3.7.4 on CentOS 7.3.

Comment: What happens for the other combinations of 3.7.4 on MacOS 10.15 and 3.7.5 on CentOS7.3?